# Specific Odd Numbered Inverted Triangle Question in C#

Tags: c#

I Would really appreciate some help on this question I will sum it up myself but also include the actual instruction and my code so far.

Write a console C# program to do the following:

1. Ask user max number of characters. This should be an odd number if user enters even number add 1 to it to convert it to odd number.
2. Ask user the character to print
3. Your program should then output two inverted vertical triangles of base equal to number entered in #1 and made of characters in #2
4. Number of characters in one line of the triangle should differ by 2 from its next line such that the top of the triangle has only 1 character.
5. The top of the triangle (single character) should be centralized appropriately
   Make sure your code follows these guidelines
   -The output string should be returned as a single string variable from a class
   -Class should have a public function that will returns the string and takes the input for #1 and #2 as argument
   -Code should be well commented and indented
   -Check for all invalid input values (e.g. for #1 no character should be accepted). Suitable message should be displayed to user for incorrect input
   -All 5 requirements should be met
   -Code should compile and run without any error or warnings

Example:
If user enters 9 for #1 and enters the character ‘*’ for #2 the program should print the following:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Thus far I can get the code to print out the correct number of characters, but not to align correctly into this shape.
I will attach my code at the bottom of this post. Whoever may respond, can you explain exactly how the for loop is working on order to achieve this? I know this is not an extremely difficult question, but C# is a new language to me, the course is entirely online, and I feel lost in such conceptual thinking. Thank you so much to whoever responds.

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n;
            char ch;
            
       
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the Max Number of Characters   ::");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                    n++;
                Console.Write("Enter Character Which You Want to Print ::");//output message for display
                ch = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//value to get from user
                Console.WriteLine(PatternPrint(n, ch));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
        public string PatternPrint(int n, char ch)
        {
            int i, j, k, l;//variable to declare
            string str = "";//string to display
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
                {
                    str = str + " ";
                }
                for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    str = str + ch;
                }
                for (l = i -1; l >= 1; l--)
                {
                    str = str + ch;

                }
                str = str + "\n";
            }
            return str;//return string
        }



        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your logic, as it prints only in one direction. Whereas, as per your requirement you need reverse direction pattern as well.

Your code output is :

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
```

Please try below code as it prints in both direction.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the Max Number of Characters   ::");
        int totalChar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        Console.Write("Enter Character Which You Want to Print ::")
        char character = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
        totalChar = (totalChar % 2 == 0) ? totalChar += 1 : totalChar;

        int mainIndex, spaceIndex, charIndex;
    
        for(mainIndex = 1; mainIndex <= totalChar; mainIndex += 2)
        {
            for(spaceIndex = totalChar; spaceIndex >= mainIndex; spaceIndex -= 2)
                Console.Write(" ");
        
            for(charIndex = 1; charIndex <= mainIndex; charIndex++)
                Console.Write(character);
        
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    
        for(mainIndex = totalChar; mainIndex >= 1; mainIndex -= 2)
        {
            for(spaceIndex = mainIndex; spaceIndex <= totalChar; spaceIndex += 2)
                Console.Write(" ");
        
            for(charIndex = 1; charIndex <= mainIndex; charIndex++)
                Console.Write(character);
        
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input : `9 & *`

Sample Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
public string PatternPrint(int n, char ch) =>
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        Enumerable
            .Range(1 - n / 2, n - 1)
            .Select(x => Math.Abs(x))
            .Select(i => "".PadLeft(i) + "".PadLeft(n - 2 * i - 1, ch)));
```

Given `5` and `#` I get:

```
  #
 ###
#####
 ###
  #
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's brief explanation from me -

**Observing example -**

**Input** => Character to use '*', Maximum it can appear is 9 times (triangle's base).

**Each line in triangle can be formatted in two ways** -

1. White spaces, then characters.
2. White spaces, then characters, then again white spaces.

**Observing your code -**

1. You seem to using the first approach.
2. Your 1st loop add white spaces.
3. You may find this surprising, but your 2nd and 3rd do the same thing, they add characters, except 3rd loop has 1 less character.

**What we need based on the example -**

1. If max character usage per line is n, we need to have n+1 lines. (One more because lower triangle does not share base)
2. A triangle completes in (n+1)/2 lines.
3. To complete upper triangle, each line needs, each line needs

   1. White spaces starting from (n-1)/2, decreasing by 1.
   2. Characters starting from 1, increasing by 2.
4. To complete lower triangle, each line needs

   1. White spaces starting from 0, increasing by 1.
   2. Characters starting from n, decreasing by 2.

I would encourage you try yourself, but after you are done, here's the reference code -

```
    public static string PatternPrint(int n, char ch)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int spaces, characters;

        // Upper triangle
        spaces = (n - 1) / 2;
        characters = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (n+1)/2; i++)
        {
            Enumerable.Repeat(' ', spaces).ToList().ForEach(space => sb.Append(space));
            Enumerable.Repeat(ch, characters).ToList().ForEach(character => sb.Append(character));
            sb.Append('\n');
            spaces -= 1;
            characters += 2;
        }

        // Lower triangle
        spaces = 0;
        characters = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < (n+1)/2; i++)
        {
            Enumerable.Repeat(' ', spaces).ToList().ForEach(space => sb.Append(space));
            Enumerable.Repeat(ch, characters).ToList().ForEach(character => sb.Append(character));
            sb.Append('\n');
            spaces += 1;
            characters -= 2;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**Above code related notes -**

1. Use StringBuilder to manipulate your string. It is more efficient, and easy I would say. Available in namespace `System.Text`
2. C# offers Linq library in namespace `System.Linq`. Enumerable used in code is part of it. It offers many more things, and extension methods. Really cool.
3. There's always room for improvement. My solution works based on assumptions. It silently fails when those assumptions are broken. Hint: evens